# UISearchBar search function does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've been trying to implement a search function onto this iOS app for quite some time.

I have a JSON file holding all the data, which is then pulled and displayed onto the table view controller.

I've implemented the search bar and followed several tutorials, this one being with the fewest issues - http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift (I've also used this too previously - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9wcKc37ZXI)

My JSON file is structured as follows:

```
{ "animal":[

    {
        "no":"001",
        "type":"dog",
        "breed":"pitbull",
        "classification":"mammal",
        "sprite":"beast"
    },
    {
        "no":"002",
        "type":"dog",
        "breed":"bulldog",
        "classification":"mammal",
        "sprite":"beast"
     },
    {
        "no":"003",
        "type":"cat",
        "breed":"birman",
        "classification":"mammal",
        "sprite":"feline"
     }

]}
```

I am calling the JSON data using a struct that is created in a separate file

**Animal.swift**

```
struct animalStruct {
    static let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("animal", ofType: "JSON")

    static let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)

    static var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
}
```

And it is called into the table view controller using the following

**AnimalTableViewController**

```
var array : NSArray = Animal.animalStruct.jsonResult["animal"] as NSArray
```

Code used for the search:

**AnimalTableViewController**

```
    @IBOutlet var segmentedSortOption: UISegmentedControl!
    var array : NSArray = Animal.pokemonStruct.jsonResult["animal"] as NSArray
    var filteredAnimal = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
        })()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return self.filteredAnimal.count
        } else {
            return self.array.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as cell
        var upperCasedNames = array[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        var searchedItem:String

        if segmentedSortOption.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
                //**ISSUE OCCURS HERE**
                myCell.name.text = filteredAnimal[indexPath.row]
                return myCell
            }
            else {
                myCell.name.text = upperCasedNames?.uppercaseString
                return myCell
            }
        } else if segmentedSortOption.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

            if let unsortedEvents = Animal.animalStruct.jsonResult["animal"] as? NSArray {
                let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: "caseInsensitiveCompare:")
                let aToZ = unsortedEvents.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
                upperCasedNames = aToZ[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
                myCell.name.text = upperCasedNames?.uppercaseString
            }
        }
        return myCell
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        filteredAnimal.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
        let arrays = (array).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate!)
        filteredArray = arrays as [[String]]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**My question**

The issue I have is that when I attempt to search via the UISearchBar, the moment I click on it, I get the "fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C". I believe this is happening because the arrays used in the tutorial is a different type compared to the ones I have used.

**UPDATE**

Firstly, the main issue was that the fact I had a different type of an array compared to the tutorial; so I had changed the `var filteredAnimal = [String]()` to `var filteredArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()` since the data source/JSON file had numerous arrays of data. And treat it as AnyObject due to that, which then allowed me to call the specific information from the JSON file.

The reason why I was returned with an empty array was because I did not assign the searched values in the empty array within the `updateSearchResultsController` method, so I had added the following just before reloading the table data - `filteredArray = arrays as [[String:AnyObject]]`

This still did not solve the issue as I had to change the if statement within the `numberOfRowsInSection` from `tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView` to `self.resultSearchController.active`, which then retrieved me an actual result.

However the search itself is still not working, but majority of the issues have been resolved. When tapping the search bar, it only retrieves the final index of the array, and when searching anything, it removes the value. I will continue to work on it and hopefully resolve the matter soon. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @EricD. Apologies, have added it now

Comment: There's no way to understand what your issue is without seeing the `UISearchBar` code. Please post that.

Comment: Thanks. But now the problem is that your question is related to code that we don't see here (UISearchBar, filteredArray). So it's going to be difficult to guess, you should add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @mattt have updated now

Comment: @EricD. have updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the last update (which has played a major part for the solution) all I did was change the NSPredicate query from `SELF CONTAINS[c] %@` to  `name CONTAINS[c] %@` and now when searching, it displays the correct matching object based on its name.

Answer (score 0):

Below link may help you to solve your issue:

[How can I fix "fatal error: can't index empty buffer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156122/how-can-i-fix-fatal-error-cant-index-empty-buffer)

```
in your code

 let arrays = (array).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate!)

will create new reference of arrays.
```

Comment: I've done a println when the search activates, the array is empty - would you have any idea why? I've followed the tutorial as is minus the data source.

As for your solution, there is a line of code already apparent:

`filteredAnimal.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)`

Thanks!